# Modify text file with math expression

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a file called POSCAR that looks like this.

```
Pt-FCC                     
3.975                      
3.975000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 3.975000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 3.975000
```

I need to change the 3x3x3 matrix several times, to take the following shape and values, where d ranges from 0.005 to 0.025 with a 0.005 increment.

```
Pt-FCC                    
3.975                      
1+d      0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 1-d      0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1/(1-d^2)
```

For example, for d=0.005:

```
Pt-FCC                    
3.975                      
1.005000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.995000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1.000025
```

I cannot assign a variable inside the file and use expr and echo to evaluate it, because the simulation program does not understand this. I am attempting to use a loop that iterates through all the values of d and copies the original POSCAR file, then uses perl, sed, or awk to modify the matrix while keeping the spacing constant.

```
for i in $(seq 0.005 0.005 0.025)
do
        cp POSCAR POSCAR_pure_shear/POSCAR_pure_$i
        perl -pi .................. POSCAR_pure_$i
done
```

I understand this is a long question and I appreciate any help that might shift me in the right direction. I am still a beginner!

Comment: Are the original values in the matrix meaningless?

Comment: They are. The structure is all what matters about the file. So the numbers matter only in terms of how many figures per column the program understands.

Comment: please update the question with your `perl/awk/sed` attemp(s) and the (wrong) output generated by said code

Comment: So do you want one output file like shown for each value of `d` ...?  Is there some special reason that you need a separate shell script _and_ another script/one-liner to process each `d`? It can all  be done very nicely in one program.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
awk -v d=0.005 'FNR==3 {$1=sprintf("%0.6f", 1+d)}
    FNR==4 {$2=sprintf("%0.6f",1-d)}
    FNR==5 {$3=sprintf("%0.6f",1/(1-d**2))}
1' file
```

Prints:

```
Pt-FCC                     
3.975                      
1.005000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.995000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 1.000025
```

Plugging that into your loop:

```
for i in $(seq 0.005 0.005 0.025)
do
    awk -v d="$i" 'FNR==3 {$1=sprintf("%0.6f", 1+d)}
    FNR==4 {$2=sprintf("%0.6f",1-d)}
    FNR==5 {$3=sprintf("%0.6f",1/(1-d**2))}
    1' file
done
```